# How to use Journey Builder workflow document format (WDF) filter criteria attribute?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

How to use (or find documentation) Journey Builder workflow document format (WDF) criteria "filterxml" attribute? I can't find any help regarding xml used in that attribute.

[Workflow Document Format](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/getting-started.html)

> criteria [String] - A string that is really XML that defines a Filter that is used as a data-gate to determine if a Contact qualifies

Example criteria from WDF page:

```
"arguments":{
     "criteria": "<FilterDefinition Source=\"SubscriberAttribute\"><ConditionSet Operator=\"AND\" ConditionSetName=\"Grouping\"><Condition ID=\"6cabf6f2-2e47-e311-8fad-463500000031\" isParam=\"false\" Operator=\"IsNotNull\"><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value></Condition></ConditionSet></FilterDefinition>"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question. At the moment, there's no easy method to create these Filters programatically. FYI, you will see these filters appear in Email app > Subscribers > Data Filters (they appear as EntryCriteria Types) but they can't be edited through the UI and there appears to be no correlation between the `filterDefinitionId` and the Filter name.

My recommendation is to create the required filters in Journey Builder, then retrieve the Journey Builder Interaction using the REST API and copy the created object in the `triggers` or `goals` array for use in a WDF Interaction object.

Incidentally, it's possible to define Filters as JSON or XML, but at this time, there's no external documentation on either approach. I did pass this feedback onto the Journey Builder Engineering team and it's definitely something that they are aware of — I hope that this is publicly documented (and supported) in the future!